# Distribution of path probabilities for a finite absorbing Markov chain

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, graph-theory, markov-chains

> I am interested in the distribution of path probabilities for a finite
>   absorbing (but otherwise well behaved) Markov chain. Has this topic
>   been considered in the literature?

A bit of Googling hasn't turned up anything for me. Of course, this translates to the distribution of path lengths in a weighted digraph since if $P$ is the transition matrix one can take negative logarithms. So treatments of that would also be of interest.

Indeed, even the simpler problem of the distribution of path lengths in a DAG doesn't turn up much for me in Google Scholar. Here of course if $A$ is the adjacency matrix then the distribution is $\mathbb{P}(\ell) = 1^* A^\ell 1/Z$, where $1$ denotes a vector of ones and $Z$ is a normalization factor. By spectral handwaving a la Perron-Frobenius (I know it doesn't really apply per se), I would expect roughly exponential decay in this case. Quick and dirty experiments show something that isn't manifestly different than that.

I am especially interested in results about multimodality of the probability or length distributions.

Comment: The distribution of path length, i.e. number of steps until reaching an absorbing state, is very well studied under names like "hitting time", "first passage time", etc.  You can get exponential decay by elementary arguments. Of course, to get detailed results you have to know something about the structure of the chain.

Comment: @NateEldredge- I'm aware of how to compute such things as you mention. But it is truly the distribution itself and in toto that interests me. In any particular case I can compute this in silico, but if there are any classes of examples you know of (other than trivialities like a 2-state chain) where the distribution is computed analytically this would be of interest to me.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying.  It seems like it would be hard to get anything in closed form in general, but there could be something for special cases.  If I think of anything I'll let you know.